# JavaScript on page reload continue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-in-loop

I've got these for in loops evaluating things so I can run some tasks `onbeforeunload`. I was wondering if there was a way to detect a simple page reload, so that I can continue and ignore it. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:** I've phrased this poorly, so I'll try again. The exit popup works fine, but I don't want it to fire when the user simply reloads the page. Is there a way to get around that? I know its poor UI, not my decision.

```
var __redirect_to = 'https://www.someplace.com';

        var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], 
            _els, 
            _i, 
            _i2;

        for( _i in _tags ) {
            _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
            for(_i2 in _els) {
                if( (_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' 
                    && _els[_i2].type != 'submit' && _els[_i2].type != 'image') 
                    || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') 
                    continue;
                _els[_i2].onclick = function() {
                    window.onbeforeunload = function(){ };
                }
            } // for in loop
       } // for in loop

        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.onbeforeunload = function() { };
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.location.href = __redirect_to;
                }, 500);
            }, 5);
            return 'Please -STAY ON THE PAGE- to take a brief survey';
        }
```

Comment: You want to persist your javascript over a page load/reload? No.

Comment: When a page gets reloaded, the JavaScript execution stops and starts again from the beginning. I don't think this can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is even possible. Maybe with some hardcore coding skills, or an clever usage of cookies. But I can't think of any reason why you'd want to have that happening.